# How to generically analyze data through code?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, generics

I have an XML file that contains a "script" of items to check and validate. What it does is reads in a value to check, and if that check is true, it does something. I originally wrote this to work with just integers, but I realize I need to make it work with more data types.

A sample check is like this...It sees if SomeValue is greater than 20.

```
<If field="SomeValue" test="@gt" value="20" />
```

*The field is just some string value. So for a double, the field would be something like 55.7.

All I do is do a int.TryParse on the value to see if I can cast the string (SomeValue) to an integer. If I can, I check to see if it is greater than 20. If not, I just assume false on the check.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could this with any data type? (i.e. string, double, DateTime)
Would Generics work? I have never used them so I dont know if they would be the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky bit is a parse when you don't know the types, but this can be done with `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`:

```
    object knownVal = 21;  //perhaps obtained from reflection
    Type type = typeof(int);
    string text = "20";
    object val = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type)
          .ConvertFromInvariantString(text);

    int rel = Comparer.Default.Compare(knownVal, val);
```

Generics *is* an option (especially with `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare`), but generics doesn't mix well with `Type` values only known at runtime. It can be done (`MakeGenericType`/`MakeGenericMethod`), but it is ugly and a bit slow.

To be honest, though: if it was me I would *assume* there is a small number of types that need handling here, and  special-case them.

Comment: But even there you are using type int. I was more looking for a way to compare values (greater than, less than, equals) without specifying a type. Not sure if thats even possible.

Comment: @Travyguy9 I'm assuming you know the type at some point, perhaps from the xml? otherwise it is an ambiguous question. Which is bigger? `10` or `2` ? (depends whether it is an int or a string...)

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I do agree I will probably need an attribute that says check it as this type. I am just trying to avoid writing all these different type evaluator methods.